# Firestore "ListenerRegistration" being called when listener is created, should be?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I'm using **Unity** with Firebase SDK, using Auth and **Firestore** utilities from Firebase.

I can make all kinds of operations to my Firestore Database from my client, so now I'm trying to implement some **client-side hooks**, so when something in Firestore changes, the client will perform an action.

The way that I'm building those listeners is inspired on [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?hl=es#c_2) and this is an example of a method that I use to set a listener to a Firestore collection if something changes:

```
//db == FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance;

public ListenerRegistration SetListenerToAllCollectionDocuments(string collectionID, Query query = null, Action OnSomeDocumentChange = null)
{
    try
    {
        Query colRef = query ?? db.Collection(collectionID);

        ListenerRegistration listener = colRef.Listen(colQuerySnapshot =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Listen changes on collection:" + collectionID);
            OnSomeDocumentChange();                
        });
        return listener;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then I can call it like:

```
ListenerRegistration listener = Database.SetListenerToAllCollectionDocuments("users", null, () => { Debug.Log("Something Change"); });
```

to have the listener reference if I want to disable it.

**So far so good, now the problem:**
This listener is correctly called when something in the database changes, but is **ALSO** called when I call the method `SetListenerToAllCollectionDocuments();` for first time, when setting the listeners.

Should be this the expected behaviour?

On my head this should only be called when something on firestore changes, not when I'm creating the listener. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did you see on link : " Not yet supported in the C # client library"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected that a listener is called with all existing data in the collection/query when you attach it.

If you want to get only new data/updates, you'll need to ensure this in your application code. The common way is to add a `lastUpdated` timestamp in each document, and then query for items where `lastUpdated` is after now.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks @Frank, I was thinking thas was a problem about metada on local changes :(

Comment: I've one doubt, if I only query for items where lastUpdated is after now, I'll never be noticed, as it is impossible that any other users make changes on future. I mean, if I do a change on 8am, people is also in 8am, so there is no "after now"...I've to store a reference for each "lastTimeIchecked" and also a "lastUpdated" or something like this? :S

Comment: The "now" depends on your use-case. If you only want to see changes since you last read the database, you'll need to know the last time you read the database and pass that in the query. But if you only want to know changes that happen after the app starts, you'd query for changes after now. If you keep a realtime listener, that will be triggered for operations made after you attach the listener.

Answer (score -1):

This method for detecting the first call works for me

```
    private bool IsSnapshotInitialCall(QuerySnapshot snapshot)
    {
        if (snapshot.Documents.Count == 0 && snapshot.Changes.Count == 0) return true;

        if (snapshot.Documents.Count > 1 && snapshot.Changes.Count == snapshot.Documents.Count) return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Then call it on the first line of every listener callback:

```
    private void MyListenerCallback(QuerySnapshot snapshot)
    {
        if (IsSnapshotInitialCall(snapshot)) return;
        // ...
    }
```